# Angular Prerendering to delay html page load for prerender to load Ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs, seo

I'm using Angular I need to delay the complete output for my page output for bots to give the content time to load before the bot stops processing the HTML. My entire page will render and the prerendering service thinks the page is complete, but ajax is still loading the data. I just need to delay the content flush until the ajax load is completely done. Is there a good way in Angular to do this?

I'm using Prerendering.io as my prerendering service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `resolve` mechanisms :

```
$module.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/actionWithAjaxData', {
            templateUrl: 'action.tpl.html',
            controller: 'ActionCtrl',
            resolve: {
                data: ['dataResource',
                    function(dataResource, APP_CONFIG) {
                        return dataResource.get(); //must return a promise
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
    }
])
.controller('ActionCtrl', ['data',
    function(data) {
        //data contains your ajax loaded data
    }
])
```

That way, the controller will be constructed only when all promises has been resolved.
If a promise is rejected, you'll need to intercept it with an error handler like `$routeChangeError`

More informations: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

That is if you want to delay the display of the page until all its ajax request are OK

If you want the other way : display page but leaving empty/hidden some part of your page while ajax is being made. You can use a watcher watching for any ajax request like the one of [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/httpRequestTracker.js) application :

```
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker', []);
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker').factory('httpRequestTracker', ['$http', function($http){

  var httpRequestTracker = {};
  httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests = function() {
    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
  };

  return httpRequestTracker;
}]);
```

and use it in a template, for example like :

```
<div class="spinner-container fade" ng-class="{in: hasPendingRequests(), out: !hasPendingRequests()}">
    <div class="spinner fade" ng-class="{in: hasPendingRequests(), out: !hasPendingRequests()}"></div>
</div>
```

That way, you'll be able to show a loader when there is a request being made...

Finally, If you want to link a specific part of your page to a specific ajax request, you can also use ajax request specific callbacks (complete/error)

Comment: wouldn't this delay anything from loading for the user until the data is loaded? I want the user to see the page but for the page not to be complete before the data has loaded. I sort of want my cake and eat it too...